# Play SoundCloud Stream with Custom Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, soundcloud

I'm having trouble playing a SoundCloud stream with a custom button.

Here's a CodePen I'm working on: https://codepen.io/tremolocreative/pen/Zepjwm

HTML

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<audio id="soundcloudPlayer"></audio>
<button></button>
```

CSS

```
button {
  background: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1055/5530/t/8/assets/play-pause-sprite.svg?2157621096199230646);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
}

button.pause-sprite {
  background-position: top right;
}
```

JS

```
var client_id = '278594df9a311b2a1a56251b3a2b0fbe';
var track_id = '293605256';

SC.initialize({
  client_id: client_id
});

SC.get('/tracks/' + track_id, {}, function(sound) {
  $('#soundcloudPlayer').attr('src', sound.stream_url + '?client_id=' + client_id);
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pause-sprite');   

    $('#soundcloudPlayer').play(); // Play track

  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: where are you passing in the sound to the function? console just shows it as object Object..  doesn't seem to be receiving the value.

Comment: That's what I'm a little unsure on... I tried following the API documentation but couldn't get it to work...

SC.stream('/tracks/293').then(function(player){
  player.play();
});

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming

Comment: I have a working fiddle but to switch to the pause sprite, you'll have to add a toggle / an if playing  then pause and add the pause class..

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen!

Comment: this is the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/gjh8dyny/ i had a go at adding the pause, based on this function view-source:http://rachelgallen.com/workingaudio.html but it didn't work the way i thought. I'll have another go later but i've some work to catch up on..

Comment: hi, just saw that you accepted my answer.. thanks :) It's always a nice start to the day.. I tried to get it fully working after I updated the snippet but to no avail.. would you mind posting the working solution if you get a chance? I was getting annoyed when it was nearly-but-not working, because I felt like there was something small (but probably blatantly obvious to someone else) that I was overlooking... thanks in advance :)

Comment: I actually still cannot get this to work properly... here's as far as I've been able to get: https://codepen.io/tremolocreative/pen/zZJjYN

The pause button doesn't work... just plays a duplicate track on top of the existing for some reason.

Comment: Hi I just woke up (I live in Ireland). That's strange! I'll have a look after breakfast...

Comment: I took a look and messed with it for a couple of hours, but couldn't get it to work. I have work of my own to finish off - I'm due to go on holidays on Thursday afternoon (haven't even packed!) but I'll take a look this evening. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: just found this! https://codepen.io/nicholaspetersen/pen/yyVYMY

Comment: also a similar question asked on the site, the asker answered his own question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15144955/1675954

Comment: did the codepen/other answer help?  Just wondering. Off on a long overdue holiday in the am.. yay... no coding for a week! if the other answer helped, make sure you upvote it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my working snippet, although it's not complete (I was having dinner, was gonna finish it before I saw your comment) Basically all that remains is to add an if-else statement to see if the audio is playing, and if it's playing then pause it. Add the pause class on pause (but remove it on play if it's there).

At the moment, in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/gjh8dyny/) the icon toggles to pause but the playing doesn't pause.. in the snippet i put an alternative version that doesn't toggle but there's a closer else-if (i didn't look at the API yet)

```js
var client_id = '278594df9a311b2a1a56251b3a2b0fbe';
var track_id = '293605256';

SC.initialize({
  client_id: client_id
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#stream").on("click", function() {
    SC.stream("/tracks/" + track_id, function(sound) {
      if (sound.currentTime > 0) {
        $('button').addClass('pause-sprite');
        sound.pause();
      } else {
        $('button').removeClass('pause-sprite');
        sound.play();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1055/5530/t/8/assets/play-pause-sprite.svg?2157621096199230646);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
}

button.pause-sprite {
  background-position: top right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
<div id='player'>
  <button href="#" id="stream">

  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: ideally, you should add an 'onended' event listener if possible and change the pause/play icon to stop when it's finished. Otherwise change it back from pause to play when it's over.. just a thought